# How to get data based on the id in an array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My data:

```
{
"created" : ISODate("2016-12-19T09:41:14.887Z"),
"students" : [ 
    {
        "student" : ObjectId("5853cb7105f1352bb5264168"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5857ab3ad6719523a86e959e"),
        "ispresent" : "No"
    }, 
    {
        "student" : ObjectId("5853cb9f05f1352bb526416a"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5857ab3ad6719523a86e959d"),
        "ispresent" : "No"
    } ]
}
```

I have to get data by student in students array and how can I get data based on the id in an array in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the dot notation within a find query

```
collection.find({'students._id': {your-id-here} })
```

for more information see - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document/#document-dot-notation

Comment: i am getting this error CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ 'students._id': '5853cb7105f1352bb5264168' }" at path "_id"

Comment: If your id is just a `string` you'll have to create an object id with `var id = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId('56cb91bdc3464f14678934ca')`